# Rebooting computer using cronjob doesn't work

Tags: server, cron, restart

I have a kiosk application running on Ubuntu Server 14.04.

In my kiosk app there is a link to reboot the system which just defaults to some PHP page that run:

```
exec('sudo reboot');
```

If the user attempts to restart the system by clicking the button which triggers the code above everything works fine - the reboot is happening.

In addition to that, I want to clean my RAM entirely every week so what I did was adding a cronjob to run every Sunday at 00:10. I've done this by:

```
sudo vim /etc/crontab
```

And then pasted the following:

```
10 00 * * * root /sbin/reboot
```

My friend is reporting me that on every Saturday morning when he looks at the Kiosk he sees that it's stuck. The message that he sees on the screen is

```
Ubuntu 14.04
. . . .[some numbers] reboot: Restarting System
```

This is an issue that he has for a few months now. What I've tried to do is editing the grub:

```
sudo vim /etc/default/grub
```

And then edit the line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=“quiet splash reboot=pci”
```

But it doesn't seem to resolve the issue.

It's important to mention that the computer isn't connected to an internet connection not my a LAN cable or WIFI.

Here is a screenshot of the issue:

[image: 4 months old photo - same issue - different numbers]

Comment: The kind of thing you describe is often due to the system waiting for network resources that aren't available. Are you mounting any external file systems? By the way, the crontab line you show will restart the machine every day at 00:10, not every Sunday.

Comment: @terdon Mybad, didn't copy it correctly. I wonder what kind of network resources it's waiting for? I think there MIGHT be a USB connected to it but this happens nonetheless. Do I have to do something to disable network? I don't need network on that computer at-all.

Comment: Well, if running `/sbin/reboot` manually as root works, it is very strange that `cron` hangs. I've just seen similar hangs on reboot when mounting external filesystems via NFS or SMB etc. I also don't think `reboot=pci` is relevant here. The problem is that the machine isn't shutting down, not that it isn't rebooting. It is stuck before shutdown is complete. Still, the first thing I would try is to disable networking (`sudo service networking stop`) and see if that lets you reboot correctly.

Comment: @terdon how can I disable the network permanently and not run this command before each reboot attempt?

Comment: Does it solve the problem? Did you try it?

Comment: @terdon I haven't. The computer is in a different location where I'm going to visit tomorrow. I will try then the solution and let you know. BTW, my friend just reported that sometimes it works and the reboot is being done and not hanging. Any idea?

Comment: That just makes it even more likely that it's a networking issue. You need to find out what the machine is mounting and how.

Comment: @terdon Is there maybe a way to disable network mounting all-together? BTW, where can I find a log of what has been mounted?

Comment: This isn't the sort of thing we can sort out in the comments. Come into the [main chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room) and ping me or one of the other regulars and we can talk about it.

Answer (score 1):

Try shutdown instead of reboot and see if it helps.  Shutdown drops into single user mode to perform the run level change.

`# m h  dom mon dow   command
10 00 * * *      /sbin/shutdown -r now`

Also, make sure you are editing root's crontab:

`sudo -i
crontab -e`

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the answer. I will be able to test it out on Sunday only as my friend is away. I will let you know when I try this. Thanks!

Comment: Hey. I was wondering, isn't it better to try maybe **/sbin/reboot --force**? According to this: http://www.techonthenet.com/linux/commands/reboot.php when we invoke the **reboot** command, it delegates to the shutdown command. However, if you specify the **--force** flag, it doesn't do so. What do you think?

Comment: I prefer to go straight to the shutdown command.  The more links in a chain the easier it is to break.  Cron is also funny about how it runs certain things.  :)

Comment: My friend has just sent another picture of the issue, it seems like it's hanging when it's trying to unmount the filesystem. I've read that reboot with the **force** flag is skipping everything and doing a hard reset so it seems like it will work. I've also read that reboot calls to shutdown internally anyways?

Comment: if its stuck unmounting a filesystem then you probably have a zombie process running that is connected to it, try "ps axo pid=,stat= | grep Z | cut -f1 -d' ' " to get a list of pid's of zombie processes then kill them before the shutdown command. This should increase your chances of a clean reboot.